# How do I downcast a class to its base type to set values using Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, callback, polymorphism, downcast, activator

**Given**

```
//all types of T inherit class name of BaseClass...
public void Test<T>(Action<T> CallBack){
  var obj = (T) Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  //Debugger shows obj of proper type and shows its proper baseclass
  //now I want to change the base class and pass in a value to affect content
  var bc = new BaseClass("Parameter1");
  //downcast the original obj to type of baseclass
  var bcObj = (BaseClass)obj;    
  //and assign the downcast object the new BaseClass   
  bcObj = bc;
  //debugger shows bcObj IS the same as bc..  
  //but callback will not send the new bcObj content...     
  CallBack(obj);
}
```

**Problem**

When the CallBack happens the change of the base class is gone!  What is seen is the same base class context seen right after Activator.Creatinstance.

**Question**

Is it not possible to downcast an object and assign values to it from another class instance of that type?

**Possible Solution**

I could contain the baseclass in the super class instead of inheriting.

Comment: You never set any values on obj or bcObj so why would you expect any change?

Comment: I don't get it. What's the point of all that `bc` code? You may as well delete everything after the `Activator.CreateInstance` line up to the line prior to `Callback(obj)`

Comment: Note the type T all inherit BaseClass, I'm trying to inject a new BaseClass into the parent class.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja I did change the entire bcObj to be the instance of bc.

Comment: Why do you expect that to change obj?  These are references, not pointers you are dealing with.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja Fair enough, how do I get it to work?

Comment: You cannot.  There isn't any pointer magic like you can do in C++.  You don't have direct access to the instance of obj at the memory level, so you can't just declare a new instance of BaseClass and assign it to the same memory, which in C++ you could do.

Comment: If all type of `T` inherit from `BaseClass` you might want to give the `Test<T>()` function a generic type constraint: `public void Test<T>(Action<T> CallBack) where T: BaseClass`...  and probably, a constructor constraint too `public void Test<T>(Action<T> CallBack) where T: BaseClass, new()`

Comment: If you look at the code closely you'll see that I was  trying to change the baseclass of object by injecting a new baseclass with parameter1.  But, when the callback happened that new base class was gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea; I thought, should have worked but did not.  However, it's a bit of an anti-pattern indeed.  I simply refactored the code to ensure strict separation of concerns and created a new class in the inheritance chain.  That solved the problem.  I simply had too much stuff going on in one of the base classes.